# Find a rigid transform that minimizes the distance under a constraint

Tags: differential-geometry, optimization

I have 4 points $p_i, \; i=1..4$  that form a rectangle and another set of 4 points $q_i$ that represent the desired position of the rectangle. I need to find a rigid transform that minimizes the distance between the actual point positions to the desired ones under a constraint that two of the 4 points of the rectangle are within a known circle of size $\alpha$. This is all in $\Bbb R^2$ so the problem is to find $x, y, \theta$ that minimize the distances.

Generally, I want to minimize the sum of distances

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{T}{\text{minimize}} & \sum\Vert T \cdot p_i - q_i\Vert\\ \text{subject to} & \Vert T \cdot p_j \Vert < \alpha, \quad j=1,2\end{array}$$

where $\alpha > 0$ is a known constant. Here's an image that explains the problem:

[image: Here's an image that explains the problem]

It would be even better if I could minimize the maximal distance rather then the sum

$$\min_{T}\max_i\Vert T \cdot p_i - q_i\Vert$$

Also it would be beneficial to add more than one circular constraint if possible.

Comment: Confusing. Please consider refining the question.

Comment: @gilad: Minimize sum of four distances between corresponding vertices?

Comment: Narasimham - yes but under the constraints described i.e., that 2 of the points stay within a given circle.

Answer (score 0):

Minimizingb the maximal distance can be formulated and solved as a Second Order Cone Problem (SOCP), with an SOCP solver, of which there are many.

min x

with respect to $T,x$

subject to

$$\|Tp_i−q_i\|_2 \le x,  \forall i$$

$$\|Tp_j\|_2 \le \alpha, j=1,2$$

This can be easily entered into a convex optimization modeling system, such as CVX, YALMIP, CVXPY, or CVXR; and solved with either free or commercial solvers called by those systems.